# Passing List<string> in WCF Rest Post Method

Tags: wcf

I am trying to pass a List in WCF Post call as parameter. Below is my code.

```
TrackingNumbers.cs

[KnownType(typeof(List<string>))]
[DataContract]
public class TrackingNumbers
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<object> TrackingNumberList { get; set; }
}

    IService.cs

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "v1/xml/GetMultipleShipmentDetails/")]
    Shipments[] XMLMultipleData(TrackingNumbers trackingNumbers);
```

Now When I am passing the following XML from fiddler

```
<TrackingNumbers xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Chhotu.Web.Partner.API">
<TrackingNumberList>10000008871</TrackingNumberList>
<TrackingNumberList>10000008864</TrackingNumberList>
<TrackingNumberList>10000008858</TrackingNumberList>
</TrackingNumbers>
```

the  XMLMultipleData method is not getting called from debugger. Please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you started your webservice application ?!

Answer (score 0):

I see some issues with our code:

- No need for [KnownType(typeof(List))], the DataContractSerializer knows this type already.
- List - is not a good approach. If you use numbers why not make it an int?

Are you sure you are attached? You can try to enforce the attaching of a debugger with Debugger.Break(); at a good position in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you try change this line

```
Shipments[] XMLMultipleData(TrackingNumbers trackingNumbers);
```

with

```
Shipments[] XMLMultipleData(TrackingNumbers[] trackingNumbers);
```

And your **[DataContract]** as

```
[DataContract]
public class TrackingNumbers
{
    [DataMember]
    public int TrackingNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

Also! Try removing `KnownType(typeof(List<string>))]`

Thanks!